# Display div on "mouseenter" and remove inner div on "click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `mouseenter` event on two elements. The `mouseenter` shows a div with content; And in each div is a button in which I'd like to attach a event to listen for a `click` or `tap` which would allow to remove itself i.e. the div.

This is the script in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  var $subnav = $('.subnav');
  $("#discover #watch").on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
      $subnav.show();
      $(".close").on('click tap', function(e) {
        if ($subnav) $subnav.hide();
        else $subnav.show();
      });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $subnav.hide();
    }
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  var $subnav = $('.subnav');

  $("#discover #watch").on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
      $subnav.show();
      $(".close").on('click tap', function(e) {
        if ($subnav) $subnav.hide();
        else $subnav.show();
      });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $subnav.hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
header nav ul:not(:hover).discover-active .discover .nav-category {
    color: #ef4b4b;
}

nav ul li .nav-category {
    padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
    height: 58px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul:not(:hover).discover-active .discover .nav-category:before {
    background-color: #ef4b4b;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.discover:hover .nav-category:before {
    background-color: #ef4b4b;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.watch:hover .nav-category:before {
    background-color: #e5059a;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}

.discover .subnav,
.watch .subnav,
.global-site-switch .subnav {
    display: none;
}

.discover .subnav img {
    width: 100%;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.discover:hover .subnav {
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 59px;
    height: 530px;
    width: 635px;
}

header nav .nav-categories .nav-category-and-subnav.watch:hover .subnav {
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 59px;
    height: 530px;
    width: 635px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-categories discover-active">
    <li class="nav-category-and-subnav discover">
      <div id="discover" class="nav-category">
        <span class="nav-category-padding">Discover</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
                                    <path d="M1395 736q0 13-10 23l-466 466q-10 10-23 10t-23-10L407 759q-10-10-10-23t10-23l50-50q10-10 23-10t23 10l393 393 393-393q10-10 23-10t23 10l50 50q10 10 10 23z"></path>
                                  </svg>
                                </i>
        <div class="subnav">
          <a href="https://jump.refinery29.com/join/24/signup-ca-refresh"><img src="images/thisweek.jpg"></a>
          <p class="close">X</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-category-and-subnav watch">
      <div id="watch" class="nav-category">
        <span class="nav-category-padding">Watch</span>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1792" height="1792" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792">
                                    <path d="M1395 736q0 13-10 23l-466 466q-10 10-23 10t-23-10L407 759q-10-10-10-23t10-23l50-50q10-10 23-10t23 10l393 393 393-393q10-10 23-10t23 10l50 50q10 10 10 23z"></path>
                                  </svg>
                              </i>
        <div class="subnav">
          <div class="column">
            Original Series
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            Trending Videos
          </div>
          <p class="close">X</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Apparently I had to update the script because I didn't realize their was CSS code which was conflicting with the JS. As a work around I have to use the jQuery selectors to actually select the `:hover` states. This script works but only once.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {

        var $subnav = $('.subnav');
        $(".close").on('click tap', function(e) {
            if (!$subnav) {
                $subnav.show();
            }
            $subnav.hide();

        });

        $('.discover:hover, .watch:hover').on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                if (!$subnav) {
                    $subnav.show();
                }
                $subnav.hide();
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                if ($subnav) {
                    $subnav.hide();
                }
                $subnav.show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you open to a pure JavaScript approach or do you only want a solution that uses jQuery?

Comment: Avoid creating event listeners inside another event listeners.  This is a quick way to duplicate bind and create logical and performance problems.

Comment: Also, given that repeating ids is a major no-no, `$("#discover #watch")` should just be `$("#watch")` as there should only be one per page.

Comment: @AndrewL Pure JS would be FAB!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pure JavaScript, you need to:

1. Make sure both your `subnav` divs are hidden by default by adding a `display:none;` css property to your `subnav` divs.
2. You can then use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to retrieve that `display` property value and based on that retrieved value, you can go ahead and toggle the `subnav` display property whenever a `mouseenter` or `mouseleave` event is triggered.
3. Finally, you can use the [parentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) property to close the parent `subnav` div whenever the child `X` element is clicked.

---

You can check out a practical example of what I described above in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/jn0d84kq/64/) or in the **Code Snippet** below:

```js
var discover = document.getElementById("discover");
var watch = document.getElementById("watch");
var close = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

function openSub(e) {
    var subNav = e.target.childNodes[5];
    var x = window.getComputedStyle(subNav);
    if (x.display == "none") {
     subNav.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     subNav.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function closeSub(e) {
    var subNav = e.target.childNodes[5];
    subNav.style.display = "none";
}

discover.addEventListener("mouseenter", openSub);
watch.addEventListener("mouseenter", openSub);

discover.addEventListener("mouseleave", closeSub);
watch.addEventListener("mouseleave", closeSub);

function btnSub(e) {
    e.target.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}

close.forEach(btn => {
btn.addEventListener("click", btnSub);
});
```

```css
.subnav { background: green;display: none;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="discover" class="nav-category">
        <span>Discover</span>
        <p>
        SVG here
        </p>
        <div class="subnav">
          <p>
          IMG here
          </p>
          <p class="close">X</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <hr>
    <li>
      <div id="watch" class="nav-category">
        <span>Watch</span>
       <p>
        SVG here
        </p>
        <div class="subnav">
          <div class="column">
            Original Series
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            Trending Videos
          </div>
          <p class="close">X</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a comma in between the two id selectors => #discover, #watch. Wrap the code in document ready to be safe and put the close event handler outside the mouse enter / leave so it only applies it once. See code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $subnav = $('.subnav');
    $(".close").on('click tap', function (e) {
        if ($subnav) $subnav.hide();
        else $subnav.show();
    });

    $("#discover, #watch").on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            $subnav.show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $subnav.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the button within the context of the clicked element:

```
$(e.target).find(".close").on ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the `.close` click event listener out of the existing `mouseenter` listener, and target the parent element.

```
$(".close").on('click tap', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

I also removed the conditional statement, as if the `.close` element can only be clicked if the parent is visible, so there's no need to watch for a "hidden parent"